# Как работать с библиотекой?

Tags: java, android, android-library

https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator/blob/master/README.md

1.Подключил либу
2.Создал вьюшку

Не знаю как картинки вставлять,чтобы они листались,подскажете?

Comment: Какие такие картинки вам листать надо? Пока что из вопроса не понятна проблема, а, значит, и ответа вы, скорее всего, не получите.

Comment: А пример от автора посмотреть? Этот контрол просто индикатор, он сам ничего не листает.

Answer (score 2):

Создайте ViewPager и привяжите к нему PagerAdapter со своими картинками. А у вашего CircleIndicator должно быть свойство setViewPager в котором указывайте ваш ViewPager